# What is the best file type to store mass data for an online dictionary or app?

Tags: android, json, dictionary

If I want to write a website or Android app for a dictionary, what is the best type of file to store the tons of words, as well as their definitions and other properties (like examples, noun or adjective), in terms of fast parsing or responding? JSON, XML, or simply txt? How to theoretically compare the actual speed?
  What is the possibly quickest response as a user to get? In other words, how to maximize the speed?

Comment: An app like dictionary would consist of a lot of structured data. SQLite should be your bet.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But could you prove to me that SQLite data requesting is better than JSON parsing?

Answer (score 0):

To create an application with a lot of data, you should really use a true database. JSON, XML, INI, YML are for "usual" objects.

You should use MySQL, SQLite, MongoDB or another DB.

- [MySQL](https://www.mysql.fr/) : If you query the Web, Web app in PHP -- SQL
- [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.org/) : If you query the Web, Web app in Javascript (NodeJS) -- NoSQL
- [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/) : To stay on the local device, it is a file, `.sqlite`. -- SQL

Comment: Thank you very much. I built websites using databases in ASP.NET MVC. But requesting data from database are very slow beyond my toleration. I am looking for better alternatives. Have you used JSON pairs for large data parsing?

Comment: Well, you can give a try. But a database use indexing to seach faster. If you want speed, with JSON like objects, use `MongoDB`. This is certainly faster than JSON. (This is a database designed for big data)

Comment: Thanks very much. I will MEAN once I have a chance.